# JS: Move a div following a defined trajectory/path

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to do an animation: move a life-belt on water very slowly, floating on the sea across waves and wind.

For code, I would like to make a div following a path. I'm using [Popmotion](http://popmotion.io/guides/introduction-to-animation) for moving and reversing the animation (with the option `{yoyo: true}`).

I saw this example but a random position is a bit tricky and creates a "stop" before running again the animation, this is not like a realtime random trajectory.
http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/375/

Is it possible to do something like this in javascript/SVG?

[image: trajectory example]

Answer (score 3):

I actually created Popmotion so I want to help you in the right direction here.

To get the non-straight lines you can play around with asymmetric easing. For example the first movement there, if you gave `y` an `easeIn` and `x` and `easeOut` the line would bend, maybe not completely to your liking but you can play around with different easing strengths to get a good combination.

You could also look into using the `Simulate` action instead of `Tween`, maybe the spring physics with a high initial `x` movement and playing around with `spring` and `friction` properties.

You don't have to use `yoyo`, you could write an `onComplete` function that starts the actor again using new randomised properties.

Hopefully some of these tips are helpful to you!